# Html form does not show up

Tags: javascript, html

```js
const toDo = [{
  task: 'Wash Plates',
  status: 'Uncompleted'
}, {
  task: 'Clean Car',
  status: 'Uncompleted'
}, {
  task: 'Work Out',
  status: 'Completed'
}]

const filters = {
  searchText: ''
}

const renderNotes = function(toDo, filters) {
  const filteredToDo = toDo.filter(function(toDos) {
    return toDos.task.toLowerCase().includes(filters.searchText.toLowerCase())
  })

  filteredToDo.forEach(function(toDos) {
    const toDoEl = document.createElement('p')
    toDoEl.textContent = toDos.task
    document.querySelector('#todos').appendChild(toDoEl)
  })

  const remaining = filteredToDo.filter(todos => todos.status === 'Uncompleted');
  console.log(remaining.length);

  document.querySelector('#todos').innerHTML = ''

  const summary = document.createElement('h2')
  summary.textContent = `You have ${remaining.length} 
      tasks that are uncompleted`;
  document.querySelector('#todos').appendChild(summary)

  filteredToDo.forEach(function(toDos) {
    const p = document.createElement('p')
    p.textContent = toDos.task
    document.querySelector('#todos').appendChild(p)


  })

}
renderNotes(toDo, filters)

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.target.textContent = 'Added a new ToDo'
  console.log('New ToDo added');

})

document.querySelector('#search-text').addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  filters.searchText = e.target.value
  renderNotes(toDo, filters)

})

// 1. Create a checkbox and setup event listener -> "hide completed"
// 2. Create new hideCompleted filter (defualt false)
// 3. Update hideCompleted on rerender list on checkbox change
// 4. Setup renderTodos to remove completed items
```

```html
<div id="div-1">
  <h1>Todo-App</h1>
  <button>Add a new ToDo</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input id="search-text" type="text" placeholder="Search todo">
  <div id="todos">
    <br>
    <br>
    <form id="new-todo">
      <input type="text" placeholder="hiya" name="text">
      <button>pressss</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <script src="todo.js"></script>
```

---

The "new-todo" form doesnt seem to appear, when i do it after my js script then it works otherwise it keeps bugging out. I think it has something to do with my js file but i cant seem to find it. It may be the div in the html file but i don't that is the case. Can someone help please.

*im not sure what else to put, it keeps asking me to put more detail as my post is mainly code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot to close the `div` tag

```
<div id="todos"></div>
```

Comment: Please don't answer questions where the solution is "Fix the typo". This type of question has no long term value since other people with the same problem are not going to find this by searching. "Typo" is one of the standard Close Vote reasons. Answering this type of question can block the OP from deleting it to remove bloat from StackOverflow. You can delete this answer to remove the possibility of blocking such clean up.

Comment: I just wanted to add a comment, but I needed 50 of reputation.
I'll delete the answer